# Data not returning from service to context when using promises

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting some data from server and have set-up this `service` on client to request them accordingly:

```
const serviceSyncFollowedArtists = async userId => {
  if (!userId) return

  const { data } = await axios.get(`${httpLink}/sync`, {
    params: {
      accessToken,
      userId,
    },
  })
  return data
}
```

service is called within `context`:

```
const syncFollowedArtists = async () => {
  await spotifyService
    .serviceSyncFollowedArtists(user.userId)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.length === 0) return
      dispatch({
        type: 'SYNC',
        data: res,
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```

It works fine as I want it to, however, before, I have set up the `service` to request data using promises:

```
const serviceSyncFollowedArtists = async userId => {
  if (!userId) return

  await axios
    .get(`${httpLink}/sync`, {
      params: {
        accessToken,
        userId,
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })
}
```

Even though I manage to obtain the data from server inside the `service`, when it's returned to the function in context, it's empty, undefined. Is threre any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting undefined because you are not returning anything from the function in the case of promises, unlike you are doing it in the first case

So just add a **return** keyword

```
const serviceSyncFollowedArtists = async userId => {
  if (!userId) return

  return await axios
    .get(`${httpLink}/sync`, {
      params: {
        accessToken,
        userId,
      },
    })
    .then(res => {
      return res.data
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })
}
```